# Преобразование запроса из IN в EXISTS

Tags: sql

Всем привет помогите с заданием - в общем само задание - показать все отделы в которых есть только один сотрудник
Вот мой CTE и запрос но с предикатом IN

```
WITH employee(firstnme, workdept) AS (VALUES ('Mich', 'B01'), ('John', 'E01'), ('Glek', 'A01'), ('Blac', 'A01'), ('Kran', 'A01'))
 
SELECT firstnme, workdept 
FROM employee 
WHERE workdept IN (
        SELECT workdept 
        FROM employee 
        GROUP BY workdept 
        HAVING COUNT(workdept) = 1)
```

Запрос вернет

```
+----+----+
|Mich| B01|
|John| E01|
+----+----+
```

Вопрос состоит в том - как сделать тоже самое, но через EXIST?

Comment: Элементарное задание на группировку и пост-отбор. Т.е. подзапрос во WHERE IN - это и есть решение. Всё остальное - WHERE IN, EXISTS - не более чем попытка заставить сервер сделать лишнюю и совершенно ненужную работу. *Запрос вернет* Результат не соответствует заданию. Вывести имя никто не просил.

Comment: Я понимаю что это и есть решение, я ведь его и написал, но мне нужно придумать решение через EXISTS, я уже 3й день разбираюсь с этими экзистами и все никак

Comment: Просто освойте разницу между обычным (независимым) и коррелированным подзапросом. Если не получается - причина именно в непонимании этой разницы.

Comment: т.е. исходя из всей этой информации что я получил этот запрос будет веным?                     SELECT workdept
FROM employee a
WHERE EXISTS ( 
        SELECT workdept 
        FROM employee b
        WHERE b.workdept = a.workdept
        GROUP BY workdept 
        HAVING COUNT(workdept) = 1)

Comment: а вот этот запрос по идее должен показать пустую строку т.к. я пытаюсь посмотреть отделы в которых нет сотрудников вообще, но в таблице таких отделов нет SELECT workdept
FROM employee a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT workdept 
        FROM employee b 
        WHERE b.firstnme = a.firstnme) ??????

Comment: Нет. Логика в случае EXISTS должна быть такой: выбрать запись, если для ЭТОГО департамента существует ДРУГОЙ (не из текущей записи) пользователь. Или наоборот - если для этого департамента не существует другой пользователь. В зависимости от исходной задачи.

Comment: вы не могли бы написать что должно быть в EXISTS?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT workdept 
FROM employee t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM employee t2
        WHERE t1.workdept = t2.workdept
          AND t1.firstnme <> t2.firstnme 
        );
```

Для понимания логики - просто переводим текст запроса на русский язык:

> Выбрать департамент, для которого не существует записи с тем же департаментом, но другим пользователем.

Comment: т.е. в экзисте будут только операторы сравнения? без всяких групировок и каунтов?

Comment: @4y4yHDpuk В данном случае - да. А в общем - подзапрос как подзапрос, там что угодно может быть наворочено. Основное - это то, что он использует значения, полученные извне (и соответственно он как бы выполняется заново для каждой отдельной внешней записи). А уж где он их там использует - во WHERE, HAVING, выходном наборе или ещё где,- определяется только требуемой логикой.